# How to add secrets to application.properties file before build step

Tags: spring-boot, github-actions, cicd

I'm using GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow to automate the build, test, deploy steps. In order to successfully build the project I need to include a secret variable (defined in the settings) to be written to application.properties file. However, at the time of building this variable is not found on the file. Here's workflow yml file

```yaml
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - harry-kart-web-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  compile:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: Running Java ${{ matrix.java }} compile
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Java version
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '11'
    - name: Compile code
      run: mvn compile



  test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: Running tests
    needs: compile
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: mvn test

  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Java version
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '11'

    - name: Adding secret
      run: |
          echo $DEV_PROP_FILE >> src/main/resources/application.properties
          cat src/main/resources/application.properties
      shell: bash
      env:
        DEV_PROP_FILE: ${{secrets.AZURE_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY}}

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: java-app
        path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: java-app

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'harry-kart-web-api'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_c1d922ca006d4e828ca9710ff6d19933 }}
        package: '*.jar'
```

Comment: Have you set it as repository secret ?

Comment: @SidharthRanasingh Yes

Comment: Can you add a link to your repo ? I think the problem is with the file path `src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: @SidharthRanasingh https://github.com/wkk91193/harry-kart

Comment: Why are you using printf [here](https://github.com/wkk91193/harry-kart/blob/d98181a7fc979cf2bb8317c2e0b2667a7031a476/.github/workflows/master_harry-kart-web-api.yml#L40) ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your variable inside of "", if you want to write them as new line to the properties.

```
echo "$PropertyString" >> path/file.properties
```

the characters ">>" will write the first part at the end of the document (as new line)

if you want to replace the file contents with yours you have to use:

```
echo $Property > path/file.properties
```

this will replace all file contents with the defined property

Variables are replaced for their names before the commands run.
I recommend you to read echo command documentation